# Remove Spket Perspective from List in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I uninstalled the Spket plugin from Eclipse, but there is still an `"<Spket IDE>"` perspective in the Perspective list.  How do I get rid of it?  I've made sure there are no more Spket directories under `eclipse_dir/plugins`, `eclipse_dir/features` and `eclipse_dir/dropins`.  Where does Eclipse keep a list of its perspectives?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do not use simple way?

Window → Preferences → General → Perspectives, select Spket IDE and press Delete button.

Comment: Wow, thanks, that worked!  Can't believe I didn't see that option.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you can fix this by starting like:

```
$ eclipse -clean
```

According to the Tasks->Running Eclipse,

> Cleans cached data used by the OSGi
>   framework and Eclipse runtime. Try to
>   run Eclipse once with this option if
>   you observe startup errors after
>   install, update, or using a shared
>   configuration.

If that doesn't work, well, 
the Eclipse ui contributions are in XML, originally all in some `plugin.xml`, which was kind of cool because the UI could then be built up on a fast scan without loading any java from all those plugins. I believe they have evolved a more complicated modularity API in recent years but you may be able to find the guilty file by grepping *.xml and *.properties for `Spket.IDE`. There is a level of indirection through the `.properties` files because strings are usually externalized for translation.

Still, you might get somewhere with something like:

```
grep Spket.IDE `find . -name \*.xml -o -name \*.properties`
```

Comment: No luck.  I searched through the entire Eclipse directory for files containing the word "spket" and found nothing.

Comment: Same here with the perspectives i want to delete.